# Convert nested list to data.frame

Tags: r, tidyverse

I got a nested list `l` with each item each self is a 2 level list. For example:

```
l1 = list("a", list("a1"= "a1v"))
l2 = list("b", list("b1" = "b1v", b2 = "b2v"))
l3 = list("c", list("c1" = c("c1v1", "c1v2", "c1v3")))
l = list(l1, l2, l3)
```

How do I tranform it to a data.frame like this:

```
df = data.frame(A = c("a", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c"), B= c("a1", "b1", "b2", "c1", "c1", "c1"), C=c("a1v", "b1v", "b2v", "c1v1", "c1v2", "c1v3"))

> df
  A  B    C
1 a a1  a1v
2 b b1  b1v
3 b b2  b2v
4 c c1 c1v1
5 c c1 c1v2
6 c c1 c1v3
```

Tried with `seperate_rows` and `map_df` but both failed to deal with inconsistent dimension of `.x[[2]]` items.

### Update 1:

@akrun's solution is not running for me: 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base R option :

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(l, function(x) {
   data.frame(A = x[[1]], B = unlist(x[[2]]), C = names(x[[2]]))
}))


#    A    B  C
#a1  a  a1v a1
#b1  b  b1v b1
#b2  b  b2v b2
#c11 c c1v1 c1
#c12 c c1v2 c1
#c13 c c1v3 c1
```

Comment: `temp` is redudant.This solution is not the most performant one. But it is easy to understand and helped me when I needed just a working solution that I translated to this one: `map_dfr(l, ~ tibble(A=.x[[1]], B=names(.x[[2]]), C= unlist(.x[[2]])))`

Comment: Yes, removed it. I was trying something and it just stayed there.

Answer (score 2):

We could use `bind_rows` with `map`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
map_dfr(l, ~bind_cols(.x) %>% 
        pivot_longer(cols = -1, names_to = 'B', values_to = 'C') %>% 
        rename_at(1, ~'A')) 
# A tibble: 6 x 3
#  A     B     C    
#* <chr> <chr> <chr>
#1 a     a1    a1v  
#2 b     b1    b1v  
#3 b     b2    b2v  
#4 c     c1    c1v1 
#5 c     c1    c1v2 
#6 c     c1    c1v3
```

Comment: thanks for the hint. a quick test returned error: `Error: Argument 2 must be length 1, not 2`

Comment: @biocyberman it could be an issue with package version as I couldn't reproduce it

Comment: I think so too.

Answer (score 2):

If the sample data in your question accurately reflects your actual data, you can try one of the following:

```
library(data.table)
data.table(l)[, list(names(unlist(l)), 
                     unlist(l, use.names = FALSE))][
                       , V3 := V2[1], cumsum(V1 == "")][V1 != ""]
##     V1   V2 V3
## 1:  a1  a1v  a
## 2:  b1  b1v  b
## 3:  b2  b2v  b
## 4: c11 c1v1  c
## 5: c12 c1v2  c
## 6: c13 c1v3  c

reshape2::melt(setNames(lapply(l, "[[", -1), lapply(l, "[[", 1)))
##   value L2 L1
## 1   a1v a1  a
## 2   b1v b1  b
## 3   b2v b2  b
## 4  c1v1 c1  c
## 5  c1v2 c1  c
## 6  c1v3 c1  c
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this is also one of the solution, I will post it here as well. This one is the one I can relate to.

```
map_df(l, ~ tibble(A=.x[[1]], B=names(.x[[2]]), C= unlist(.x[[2]])))
```

Read:

Run through all elements of `l` and make a data.frame (`map_df` and `~` inside) from a sub-data.frame created by `tibble` where column `A` = ..., `B` = ..`, ...

Thanks go to:

1. @akrun for prompt answer, I could have used the solution, but was
   too busy to figure out.
2. @[A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61788395/588867) also provided a
   performant answer.
3. @Ronak Shah provided a [plain R base
   solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61787225/588867) that I can translate to this.